# Avoid double processing pending order (cron/landing site)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've implemented a custom  payment method in magento. In short, it works the following way:

- upon checkout, the user gets redirected to the bank
- he enters his credit card info, returns to a landing page
- landing page querys the bank for the results and sets the order/payment status accordingly

Also, since the user might not return:

- a cron querys the bank every minute for the status of the pending payments and updates them if neccessary

The problem: when the cron runs at the same time the user is returning, the payment statuses get updated twice, two invoices are generated, two emails are sent, etc.

There must be a proper way of handling this. Maybe locking the order/payment entity somehow? I'm kind of new to magento. Please share your knowledge!

Comment: Why not skip the query on the landing page and do cron only? If the landing page gets hit you could have an ajax script query your Magento for order status changes.

Comment: If the cron is only as a backup, why not add a delay into your cron script so that it only updates the order status if say 15 minutes has passed since the order was placed, and it keeps doing this every minute until 15 minutes have gone by. I do this for all pending payment paypal orders and pick up any missed IPNs but only update the order status once one hour has passed since the order was placed. 15 minutes could probably go down to say 5 or maybe lower but you might need to play with this.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas, for the time being I turned off the processing on the landing page.